Cypress not able to call http xhr on different localhost port
I'm running and angular app (angular 18) in dev mode (npm run start), the app runs on http://localhost:4200/.
I have a simple Cypress test to visit the home page and check the title of the app.
When running the test: (cypress open --browser chrome), my app is not able to call public API of the backend that is running on http://localhost:16105/.
If I use curl to call the endpoint directly, the endpoint works correctly.
The angular app is calling multiple public API when loading and the problem occur on each.
cypress.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
  projectId: "XXXXX",
  defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,
  requestTimeout: 10000,
  chromeWebSecurity: false,

  retries: {
    runMode: 3,
    openMode: 0,
  },

  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
    experimentalStudio: true,
    excludeSpecPattern: "*.js",
    specPattern: ["cypress/e2e/**/+(all.ts|*.cy.ts)", "cypress/e2e/**/**/*.cy.ts)"],
  },
});


Nodejs version : 20.18.0
Angular 18


This question has similarities 504 error when running cypress

What happens if you try http://localhost:16105/ in a cy.request()?

Calling directly http://localhost:16105/ in a cy.request() works correctly
